# RegEx to Extract folder ID from GDrive URLs using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, regex

Somebody knows how to extract the id from Google Drive URL?

normally the url is like this:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/xxxxxxyyyyyyaaaaazzzzzzz

how can i extract the id 'xxxxxxyyyyyyaaaaazzzzzzz' ?

Comment: If the format is always the same, using `str.split('/')[5]` should do it

Comment: So, do you want to do it in PHP or JS? Pick one or the other. You should also include what you've tried so far.

Comment: in php https://eval.in/1013433

Comment: I want to do this in PHP, but if the URL contains more fragments retrieved from Database? like: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/id/xxxxxxyyyyyyaaaaazzzzzzz

Comment: Use explode and instead of  the index, use `end()`

Comment: yeah, thanks that (end()) works!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*in php u can use `explode` to get like this;*

```
$url = 'https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/xxxxxxyyyyyyaaaaazzzzzzz';
$arr = explode('/', $url);
echo $arr[5];

/* OR  you can also use like this */
echo end($arr);
```

working demo : https://eval.in/1013442

For more : http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php